# Libgdx x and y difference

Tags: java, libgdx

In the picture below you can see that I have drawn a black circle into the screen and in the code I have tried to get the black circle to match the coordinates of the clear circle which is my physics body which is completely working.

My problem is when I move the clear circle around my map the black circle stays there in the corner. The black circle moves a little about a few pixels so it seems its mmoves around a bit but very scaled down and I don't know why. Thanks.

[image: xydifference]

```
 public void update(float dt){
        handleInput(dt);

        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);

        player.update(dt);

        camX();

        gameCam.update();
        renderer.setView(gameCam);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();

        renderer.render();

        b2dr.render(world, gameCam.combined);

        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(ball,player.getX() , player.getY(), 70, 70);
        game.batch.end();

    }

    public void camX(){
        gameCam.position.x = gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2;
        if(player.b2Body.getPosition().x  >= gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2){
            gameCam.position.x  = player.b2Body.getPosition().x;
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class Character extends Sprite {
    public World world;
    public Body b2Body;
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public Character(World world){
        this.world = world;
        defineMario();
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
      setPosition(b2Body.getPosition().x,b2Body.getPosition().y );
    }
```

Comment: FYI, there's a game-dev stack exchange site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com -- you will probably get a better response there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the Batch's projection matrix to the UI's camera for UI drawing, but you never change it to the `gameCamera`'s projection before drawing your game elements. Before the `game.batch.begin();` line you need to add `game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCamera.combined);`.

By the way, it doesn't make sense for Character to extend Sprite, since you don't use Character for drawing anything, only for tracking a position.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
    public class Character extends Sprite {
        public World world;
        public Body b2Body;
        public float x;
        public float y;

        public Character(World world){
            this.world = world;
            defineMario();
        }

        public void update(float dt) {
         //so the sprite and body will have the same center
         setPosition(b2Body.getPosition().x-getWidth()/2, b2Body.getPosition().y- getHeight()/2 );

          setCenterOrigin(); // to handle when body does a rotation
        }
```

please, tell me if it works or not in comment

Good luck

Comment: It still does the same. The black circle moves but very scaled down so I think it may be to do with that.